# How to enter value for foriegn key field via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have models:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='parent_post', lazy='dynamic')


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

When entering a post to database I do this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
      post = Post(body=form.post.data, author=g.user)
      db.session.add(post)
      db.session.commit()
```

This is working right.

But how can I enter a comment to database if I want to pass the 'post.id' value directly 
instead of object 'post'. (Not able to 'pass' object via form in html)

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
      comment = Comment(body=form.post.data, parent_post=form.p_id.data)
      db.session.add(comment)
      db.session.commit()
```

currently `p_id` holds value `post.id` and it gives me error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment.parent_post` is a relationship, backed by the integer column `Comment.post_id`.  Currently, you are trying to assign an int (from `form.p_id`) too the relationship.  Assign an int to the column or a `Post` instance to the relationship.

```
comment = Comment(post_id=form.p_id.data, body=form.post.data)
# or
post = Post.query.get_or_404(form.p_id.data)
comment = Comment(parent_post=post, body=form.post.data)
```

The second way is preferable, because you validate that a post with the id exists before trying to use the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
      comment = Comment(body=form.post.data, parent_post=form.p_id.data)
      ### you need to add `comment` instead `post` in the line below
      db.session.add(comment)
      db.session.commit()
```

I strongly think that an error was because of the `db.session.add(post)`. Please the line `db.session.add(post)` with `db.session.add(comment)` while adding the comments.

Please make sure that POST-ID that being passed through the form is existing in the `post` table.

Comment: I know that is an error. But its not in my real code. Problem is something else. I have edited question now

Comment: You must ensure that you are posting the exact code. Please correct the post on very priority basis.